# Running Python Code from Website via PHP - but how to disable button after it is puhed

Tags: php, python, html, button

Help with the following

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['MEASURE']))
    {
        shell_exec("sudo python /var/www/html/lab/mkdir.py");

    }
?>
```

HTML PART

```
<form method="post" >       
<input type="submit" value="Start Measuring" name="MEASURE" class="search">
</form>
```

I try to use a HTML page with a button to execute a Python script via PHP -> this works... However when I try to disable the button once clicked to avoid multiple starts of the Python script using "onClick="disableButton();" or similar the script will not be executed anymore....

Comment: Your web server's user can execute `python` as root without a password, but yet you're worried about making a simple JS snippet to disable a button when it's pressed? Honestly this looks like a very bad idea to me. The button should be the least of your worries until you fix the security implications of this. What does your python script do? Can you not set it up so that it is executable by the web server's user? Could it not be rewritten with PHP so that you can avoid `shell_exec` altogether?

Comment: To properly and securely stop an user accessing something multiple times you have to use the user's IP address (not the best way as one can refer to multiple users) or enforce a cookie session (that's how it is done). Buttons, links and other clickables are the least of your worries if you are trying something this crazy. At least remove sudo from the Q, its ugly even to see it there.

Comment: Certainly these are all valid comments, however please don't be concerned about those aspects. It's a test environment on a single machine. I just wondered what is preventing the submit of the signal to start the execution of the script when the button got disabled. But without disabling it is functioning.

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery you can try:

```
<form method="post" >       
    <input type="submit" id="exec" value="Start Measuring" name="MEASURE" class="search">
</form>
```

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#exec').click(function(event) {
        $(this).html('Please wait...').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

[This allows only 1 click on the button. But if the form is sent to the same page, it will be reloaded and the button will be enabled xD]

good luck!